# Displaying radio-fields in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two radio button options, that one of it has next to it a textfield. The radiofield with the textarea next to it are showing. However the first radiofield (small) isn't showing. Any help on why?

```
size= Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            flex: 1,
            defaultType: 'radio', 
            width:'100%',
            border:false,

            items: {
                checked: true,
                boxLabel: 'Small',
                name: 's',
                inputValue: 'small',

           },

            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [
            {
                boxLabel: 'Large',
                name: 's',
                inputValue: 'l',
            },
            {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
            },                            
            {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'specify'

            }
            ]
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a mock-up/picture of the layout and what you want to accomplish? I see a lot what's wrong, so I can't see what you want.

Comment: @Tarabass i'm trying to accomplish something like this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2kj

Comment: @Tarabass thank you for your help, if i may one question, i'm trying to find the equivalent of header tag in extjs, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a container around the hbox. You are now override the first `items array` with the second `items array`. You can only have one `items array` per container/wrapper.

```
size= Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    flex: 1,
    defaultType: 'radio', 
    width:'100%',
    border:false,
    items: {
        checked: true,
        boxLabel: 'Small',
        name: 's',
        inputValue: 'small'
    }, {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [
        {
            boxLabel: 'Large',
            name: 's',
            inputValue: 'l',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'splitter'
        },                            
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'specify'
        }]
    }
});
```